# p=np problem's official description is easy to solve?

Tags: algorithms

In the official link of the P=NP problem at the below page: 
http://claymath.org/millennium-problems/p-vs-np-problem 
, there is mentioned a problem of organizing housing accommodations for a group of four hundred university students and where the hostel capacity is 100 at max and also the dean has given a list of pairs of students who are 'incompatible', that is, they can't be accomodated together. The problem further states that building such a list from scratch would be difficult/hard. But, I did some thinking and came up with below solution:
We proceed by counting the exact number of pairs possible which can be done as follows:
1st we select 100 students out of 400 available students.=(400C100) ways.
Next, we select 2 students out of each of the 100 students' set in 100C2 ways. 
Then for each of the set it is "added" to the final result set if that pair does not exists in the dean's pair of incompatible set. 
I know that this process of making a list will take a long time as the list itself is very long. But, if we consider the 1st combination set of 100 students out of 400 students for the sake of LUCK for the few lucky students( I mean if it is sort of a lucky draw and only the 1st set of 100 students is finally selected), then it will be an easy problem altogether!
Anyways, we can 'tell' in this problem that solution set exists or not as we can directly say if any pairs are possible by looking at the dean's list of incompatible students as all those and only all those should not be in the result set so if there are 50 such pairs that means there are 100 incompatible students and we can select the 1st 50 from this list and other 50 from remaining of the 350 students? This does not seem 'HARD' as the 3SAT problem where just telling that a solution exists is enough. (As in this case the total number of combinations are 400C100 * [ 100C2 - the number of pairs that are in the selected list and in the dean's list also]
(This can also be written as 400C100 * [ 100C2 MINUS pairs in the dean's list], where MINUS is the operation in the database terminology.
Plus I have another idea - There can be 400 C 2 possible pairs out of the available 400 students out of which [400 C 2 - the dean's list pairs] is the pairs we want and this set will have multiples of one student in pairs like A with B or A with C etc. so we can store these multiples against each student and finally we can take 50 pairs out of them in Permutation of [Available pairs-Duplicates] and that will not be a huge task I suppose.(Linear Complexity?)
You will have the answer set combination options built beforehand as I said and you just need to select all combos to make the final collection of possibilities: For example 6 students A,B,C,D,E and F are there and only 4 can be allocated room (2 in 1 room). Next suppose these are the incompatibles: A C , D E and E F. Then the total possibilities will be 6C2 - 3= 15 pairs will be possible but that set will be like A B, A D, A E that is multiple pairs will be there having duplicate(A in this case-others will be like B C, B D, B E or C E, C D, C F etc.) so we will group them out together and take all combos one by one like A B, C E, D F and then A D, B E, C F etc. There can't be any Backtracking in this case can it be?
Please shed some light on my research and if I am right or wrong?

Comment: $\binom{400}{100}$ is out of range, both time-wise and space-wise.

Comment: But we can use the dean's list to find out if there indeed can be an accomodation of 100 students at least?

Comment: No, the probability of success will be so close to zero that you would have much better chance of winning the lottery.

Comment: Plus I have another idea - There can be 400 C 2 possible pairs out of the available 400 students out of which [400 C 2 - the dean's list pairs] is the pairs we want and this set will have multiples of one student in pairs like A with B or A with C etc. so we can store these multiples against each student and finally we can take 50 pairs out of them in Permutation of [Available pairs-Duplicates] and that will not be  a huge task I suppose.(Linear Complexity?)

Comment: If it's fast, it will reach a dead-end, forcing a backtrack. The total length of all the likely backtracks will be exponential.

Comment: What you need to do to get a sense of the hopelessness of your various proposed strategies is to write a program and test it on random data sets.

Comment: The retelling of the illustrative problem is garbled and apt to frustrate Readers.

Comment: @quasi, I have added the content in question so you can explain if any 'Backtracking' would be there in the generating the final result set.

Comment: Yes, there will be backtracking. Early placements can lead to later deadlocks. But as I said, rather trying than discuss it abstractly based on vague, poorly specified strategies, you need to _implement_ your ideas, and test to see what happens.

Comment: There can be backtracking in generating combinations?

Comment: I have no more time for this, sorry -- implement your ideas and then you'll know.

Comment: Somehow you seem to be assuming that there are only 50 pairs of incompatible students. That is not specified anywhere in the problem.

Comment: I meant that 50 pairs containing distinct students would suffice to have chosen 100 students.

Comment: Ah, I think I got your misunderstanding. The task is not to fill 50 two-bed rooms, but to fill one big dormitory room with 100 beds, And if the pair (John,Joe) is on the dean's list, then John and Joe are not allowed both to be in the dorm _anywhere_.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I got it the other way- that there were 50 double beds in the dormitory. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are not getting a sense of the kind of numbers we are dealing with here. The number $400\choose 100$ is roughly $10^{96}$. Suppose you had a trillion computers ($10^{12}$), testing a trillion pairs per second ($10^{12}$). The number of seconds since the Big Bang is estimated to be around $10^{18}$. So you have your trillion computers running a trillion tests a second since the universe began (let's forget the impossible energy and space requirement here). That would let you test $10^{12+12+18}=10^{42}$ pairs; so you are off by a factor of $10^{54}$. You can multiply the number of computers by a million, speed them to a million times the speed, and still you wouldn't test any significant part of the sample.

The P=NP problem is not about algorithms that are "hard to find". It's about algorithms that are "hard to compute" in the sense above. The question is whether there is a "shortcut" (i.e., polynomial time) for all those problems.

Comment: is the 2nd algorithm in my edited answer using 400C100? It uses 400C2 and then just finds out all the combinations having students in 50 pairs set. If there is no subset for a student say x like x A, x B or x D then we can discard such student from the final set. And if there is no such 50 pair set then it is like UNSAT!

Comment: @Martin Argerami: Actually, $\binom{400}{100}$ is only about $10^{96}$, which, while a lot less than $10^{400}$, is still blatantly out ot range.

Comment: I was literally working on the back of an envelope. Let me check what I did.

Comment: I have edited the answer to fit the  new numbers.